# Running dart run build_runner build in DockerFile does not generate files

Tags: flutter, dart, dockerfile, build-runner, dart-frog

I have a DockerFile as follows:

```
FROM dart:stable AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy Dependencies
COPY packages/shared ./packages/shared

# Install Dependencies
RUN dart pub get -C packages/shared

# Resolve app dependencies.
COPY pubspec.* ./
RUN dart pub get
RUN dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
RUN dart run stormberry migrate --no-ssl --db=postgres --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --password=postgres --apply-changes

# Copy app source code and AOT compile it.
COPY . .
# Ensure packages are still up-to-date if anything has changed
RUN dart pub get --offline
RUN dart compile exe bin/server.dart -o bin/server

# Build minimal serving image from AOT-compiled `/server` and required system
# libraries and configuration files stored in `/runtime/` from the build stage.
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /runtime/ /
COPY --from=build /app/bin/server /app/bin/


# Start server.
CMD ["/app/bin/server"]
```

This is for a server app built using `dart_frog`. I have used `stormberry` package as an ORM for postgres db. Now, stormberry requires me to run `build_runner` for generating the schemas before migrating it to the database.

The issue is that, the code generation is not generating the `schemas.g.dart` files which is required for the migration to happen. This container is deployed to Google CloudRun. This is the log which I get from the CloudRun logs:

```
Step 7/15 : RUN dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
 ---> Running in 3a5efb6b628b
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 612ms

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 14.0s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.3s

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 2ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 7ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 60ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 81ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)

Removing intermediate container 3a5efb6b628b
 ---> e92can43b7d7
Step 8/15 : RUN dart run stormberry migrate --no-ssl --db=postgres --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --password=postgres --apply-changes
 ---> Running in 09c17e19f518
Could not run migration, because there are no models found. Did you run the build?
The command '/bin/sh -c dart run stormberry migrate --no-ssl --db=postgres --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=leoncoeur --password=AlphaOmega@1727 --apply-changes' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

---

This results in stormberry throwing the following error:

```
Could not run migration, because there are no models found. Did you run the build?
```

How do I fix this?

---

***EDIT:***

This runs fine in my local machine however.
This is the expecting output for generating one `schema.g.dart` file.

```
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 811ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 122ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 749ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 6.9s
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 69ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 7.0s with 0 outputs (8 actions)
```